# relocatable rpm --install fails with error: unpacking of archive failed on file /utp: cpio: mkdir failed - No such file or directory

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Given this spec

```
Name:       utp
Version:    1.0
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    some summary

Group:      Applications/Engineering
License:    Proprietary
URL:        http://www.example.com
Source0:    %{name}-%{version}.tgz
BuildArch:  noarch
Prefix:     /opt

%undefine __brp_mangle_shebangs

%description
A very nice description

# get a list of the files
%prep
# tar -zvtf %{SOURCE0} | awk '{printf "/opt/%s\n", $NF}' > %{_tmppath}/files.list
tar -zvtf %{SOURCE0} | awk '{printf "/%s\n", $NF}' > %{_tmppath}/files.list
tar -zxvf %{SOURCE0}
echo "=== prep ... done"

# no build here
# %build

%setup  -q
echo "=== setup ... done"

%install
cp -r ./* %{buildroot}
echo "=== install ... done"


%clean
echo "=== clean ... done"

# %files -f %{_tmppath}/files.list
%files
/%{name}
%defattr(-,root,root)
```

I can create a my rpm package which seems to be relocatable

```
medi@medi:~/work> rpm -qp --queryformat "%{prefixes}\n" rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/utp-1.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm 
/opt
```

But fails at installation with

```
medi@medi:~/work> rpm -i --prefix /tmp/opt rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/utp-1.0-1.el8.noarch.rpm  --dbpath /tmp/mydbpath --nodeps
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /utp: cpio: mkdir failed - No such file or directory
error: utp-1.0-1.el8.noarch: install failed
```

My intention here is to install this package in /tmp/opt and use test dbpath.

During %files processing I see

```
Processing files: utp-1.0-1.el8.noarch
D: /home/medi/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/utp-1.0-1.el8.x86_64/utp: directory
D: /home/medi/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/utp-1.0-1.el8.x86_64/utp/README.txt: ASCII text
D: /home/medi/work/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/utp-1.0-1.el8.x86_64/utp/utg: directory
etc etc
```

I have a feeling I need to have '/opt' somewhere in my %files or %install 
Can you tell what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding more instructions in %install and %files.

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt/
cp -r ./* %{buildroot}/opt/utp

%files
/opt/%{name}
```